# background image not visible in iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, safari

I have a background image for an input box..It works fine in IE/FF, but for some reasons it is not visible in iPad Safari..Below is the CSS for the same;

```
#rightContent  .inputBox{
background:transparent url(images/keyback.gif) no-repeat scroll center 6px;
border:0pt none;
float:left;
height:40px;
#height:37px;
margin-left:10px;
width:450px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest splitting out the `background` style into seperate parts. Not all browsers support `transparent` (and possibly other parts of that style).

When a browser sees a style they don't know what to do with, they usually ignore the whole style. Putting the `background-image` onto it's own line (eg. it's own style) will let that property get picked up by browsers that can deal with it, rather than getting missed because it is lumped in with things the browser doesn't know about.

Comment: I did try 2 things;
1. Splitting the background into separate parts as you said &
2. Add the background image as an inline style..

Still does not work...

Also the same issue is there in desktop Safari as well...Not sure if it has got anything to do with using "transparent"..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default value of background-color is transparent. Have you tried not setting a color? Also, since you have a set image with no-repeat, why not make the image a jpg/png and set a color to match the background-color you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and have managed to get a working solution using jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var buttonsFilename = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Buttons.png") %>';

        $('.commands .command').css({
            background: 'url(' + buttonsFilename + ')',
            width: '55px',
            height: '55px',
            display: 'inline-block'
        });
    });
```

I'm using this within an ASP.NET MVC website, hence the `<% %>` tag.

I could only get it to work using the background shortcut css property. I couldn't get any of the following to work ...

- background-image
- backgroundImage
- 'background-image'

... when using the object notation. Unfortunately that wipes out any other background settings you may have. But I got around that by using another piece of jQuery to set my `background-position` property.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, but I found that the image slice I was using was too thin to display on iPad. It is a texture, so I was using a 15px slice and an x-repeat, which is fine in all browsers but not iPad. After some experimenting I found that the threshold for iPad seems to be 130px.